# Does $Ax=b$ have a solution $a\ge 0$ when $A_{ij} > 0$ for $i\le j$ and $A_{ij} < 0$ for $i> j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, linear-programming

Write $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n) > 0$ when $x_1 > 0, \dots, x_n > 0,$ and $x \ge 0$ when $x_1 \ge 0, \dots, x_n \ge 0.$

Consider an invertible square matrix $A$ that satisfies
$$
A_{ij} > 0 \text{ for } i \le j, \qquad \text{ and } A_{ij} < 0 \text{ for } i > j;
$$
and a vector $b > 0.$
Let $x = A^{-1}b$ solve the linear system $Ax = b.$
Is $x \ge 0$?

My thoughts so far:

- Clearly, $x$ has at least one positive element.
- $A$ looks somewhat related to the class of Z-matrices. Do matrices that look like $A$ also have a name?
- [Farkas' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas'_lemma) might be helpful.

**Edit:** Even though $x\ge 0$ is not true in general (see copper.hat's counterexample below); are there sufficient conditions that one can impose on $A$?

Answer (score 2):

$101 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 100 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -99 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe there are some sufficient conditions on $A$ to make $x \ge 0$?